# Spatial Interpolation of Point Layer with Count and Associated P-Value

Tags: python, interpolation, statistics

Here's quick synopsis of the data I have. I have a dataset of just under 100 points with most points being coincident with several other points resulting in roughly 15 unique locations. Each point represents 1 day of passively collected audio data. The audio data has been run through a separate program to count the number of times a specific sound is heard. It then assigns a p-value to that count total (I assume based on training data in the program) to represent the confidence that the software has for that call being associated with a specific source. What I need to generate is an interpolated prediction surface that predicts the counts of the data across the study area with influence/preference given to count values associated with a lower p-value. Spatial interpolation is not my strong suit, but I can generate a prediction surface on just the counts, but I can't find a way to have it influenced by the p-values outside of the geostatistical wizard. Ultimately, this method will be incorporated into a script tool, so I need to be able to code it with the python libraries available in ArcGIS Pro, but I don't know what method to use. Any help is appreciated. I am not asking for a code sample as I can code it in once I have a method. It is the method I am seeking assistance with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"with influence/preference given to count values associated with a lower p-value"
I don't think there's a native interpolation tool with this functionality. So you may have to do some data manipulation to achieve the same effect.

A simple way to do this would be to duplicate points that have p-values below a certain threshold and merge them to your dataset. This will effectively give them more weight when you run the interpolation.

Another more complex option would be to do a weighted average of all the colocated points, giving more weight to those points with lower p values. Then interpolate the surface based on the averages.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a weighted average. That should work nicely! Thanks